# Three area Nav bar in Bootstrap

Tags: html, css, nav, twitter-bootstrap-2

I'm trying to create a bootstrap nav bar with three areas. Left, Middle, and Right.

Left side will have a user avatar portrait bar, middle will be a search bar, and right will be some buttons.

I'm having trouble centering the search bar. Any ideas on how to implement this? I would post my attempt, but it's become so cluttered its quite unreadable now.

After a few edits and help from those below. I  have done this.
http://www.bootply.com/azFiegnAoO

But now there is a small problem, the width of the navbar set at 100% is wider than the page and extends a page a bit to the right.

Comment: Something like this? -> http://www.bootply.com/mQh8DyRfWY

Comment: Does this work in bootstrap 2.3.2? It's great! Does it have to be the 'brand' class?

Comment: Doesn't have to be the brand class. There are minor changes for Bootstrap3. You can inspect it and you should be fine

Comment: After a few edits and help from those below. I have done this. http://www.bootply.com/azFiegnAoO

But now there is a small problem, the width of the navbar set at 100% is wider than the page and extends a page a bit to the right.

Comment: Well thats another problem, look in to your container and inspect what it's causing it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

set the width of the left and right part of the navbar to be equal and add `margin: 0 auto` to the css of the navbar

Comment: What do you mean? Will the left and right part of the navbar still be responsive?

Comment: yes if you use percentages for the widths. for instance 20% for the left and right and 60% for the middle navbar

Comment: of the entire navbar class?